# Grouping list into sublists based on string sequences

Tags: python, python-itertools

I need to split a list into sublists based on sequences of strings present in a text file as shown below (note that the sublists may not overlap and that you can't have a pattern that is a subset of another).

```
Patterns:
cat,dog
dog,cow

list = ['chicken','cat','dog','dog','cow','bat']

Output: [chicken,[cat,dog],[dog,cow],bat]
```

Certainly, I can do this in a native way using some list splits and merging back together again at the end (see edit2) but this is ugly, and I figured there must be a more pythonic way to do this. There are some similar questions that use `itertools` or similar, but none of them are quite what I want (they mostly involve matching on a common characteristic, which isn't present here).

Edit: list items can occur multiple times (so a pattern may occur more than once). Patterns can also contain any number of elements > 1

Edit 2: Something like the following is the native approach I was thinking  of. Note that I havent implemented this and it most likely has several issues (including that I'm not inserting at the proper indices in the second for loop), but I think it demonstrates the algorithm I thought of at first.

```
l1 = input list
list l2 = [100]  #Just preseting the size for now
for pattern in patterns:
    find(index where pattern starts in l1)
    s = split list (start of pattern:end of pattern)
    list[start of pattern] = s
for l in l2:
    if l2[l] is empty:
        l2[l] = l1[l]
```

Comment: do all patterns include two items? And what would be the expected output if it were `['chicken','cat','dog','snake','dog','cow','bat']`? And do patterns match only once or potentially multiple times (i.e.what would  `['cat','dog','cat','dog','cat','dog']` give)?

Comment: It could be helpful if you showed your approach "using some list splits and merging back together again at the end". Maybe that would make it easier to help you find a "less ugly" solution.

Comment: okay if they can be any length, what would happen if a pattern is a subpattern of another pattern? For example `cat` and `cat,dog` and `cat,dog,cat` and the list would contain a `cat,dog,cat` somewhere?

Comment: Upon thinking about this, the patterns don't need to overlap. You could get around that by just rerunning the script twice with a different set of patterns. So you cant have a pattern that is operating on the same elements as another. They get "eaten" once theyre processed. I'll update my example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems like it meets your requirements, It uses the optional `else` clause that `for` loops can have to handle the case when none of the patterns matched (and the current element should just be copied to the `result`).

```
patterns = ['cat', 'dog'], ['dog', 'cow']
elements = ['chicken', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'cow', 'bat']

result = []
i = 0
while i < len(elements):
    for pattern in patterns:
        if pattern == elements[i: i+len(pattern)]:
            result.append(pattern)
            i += len(pattern)
            break
    else:
        result.append(elements[i])
        i += 1

print(result)  # -> ['chicken', ['cat', 'dog'], ['dog', 'cow'], 'bat']
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Wasn't aware there was such a thing as an else clause for a loop. I've never seen it in other languages. I suppose this is one of those rare cases where its a bit of useful syntactic sugar +1.

Comment: user979616: Yes, the `for/else` a very "Pythonic" thing. I don't use it much, but it does save some additional coding and the introduction of flags, etc, allowing slightly simpler, as well as more elegant and readable code to be written—so it's good to be aware of its availability. Also note that `while` loops can have them, too, although the meaning is slightly different.